# Docker Nexus Repository - Keep stuck on Initializing

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, nexus3

I'm trying to access Nexus Repository home page by browser but the page keep on `Initializing...` indefinitely.

Browser: http://<server_ip>:8081/

docker-compose:

```
cup-nexus:
    image: sonatype/nexus3
    restart: always
    container_name: cup-nexus
    volumes:
      - /DevOps/volumes/nexus-data:/nexus-data
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    networks:
      - wso2_bridge
```

Docker Container logs:

```
2023-05-11 20:48:41,109+0000 INFO  [jetty-main-1] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.repository.httpbridge.internal.ViewServlet - Initialized
2023-05-11 20:48:41,135+0000 INFO  [jetty-main-1] *SYSTEM org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@44379b0f{Sonatype Nexus,/,file:///opt/sonatype/nexus/public/,AVAILABLE}
2023-05-11 20:48:41,169+0000 INFO  [jetty-main-1] *SYSTEM org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector - Started ServerConnector@5a750c01{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8081}
2023-05-11 20:48:41,170+0000 INFO  [jetty-main-1] *SYSTEM org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - Started @32769ms
2023-05-11 20:48:41,170+0000 INFO  [jetty-main-1] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.JettyServer - 
-------------------------------------------------

Started Sonatype Nexus OSS 3.53.0-01

-------------------------------------------------
2023-05-11 20:48:44,548+0000 INFO  [quartz-12-thread-1] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.quartz.internal.task.QuartzTaskInfo - Task 'System - Repository Health Check: maven-central' [healthcheck] state change WAITING -> RUNNING
...
2023-05-11 20:52:08,780+0000 INFO  [qtp192929389-86] *UNKNOWN org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.AbstractValidatingSessionManager - Enabling session validation scheduler...
2023-05-11 20:52:08,788+0000 INFO  [qtp192929389-86] *UNKNOWN org.sonatype.nexus.internal.security.anonymous.AnonymousManagerImpl - Loaded configuration: OrientAnonymousConfiguration{enabled=true, userId='anonymous', realmName='NexusAuthorizingRealm'}
2023-05-11 20:53:31,381+0000 WARN  [qtp192929389-87] *SYSTEM org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection - 
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection.lambda$failedCallback$0(AbstractConnection.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
2023-05-11 20:53:37,261+0000 WARN  [qtp192929389-80] *SYSTEM org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection - 
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection.lambda$failedCallback$0(AbstractConnection.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
2023-05-11 20:53:50,795+0000 WARN  [qtp192929389-83] *SYSTEM org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection - 
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

Versions: 
Docker-Compose: 3 
Nexus Repository: 3.53.0-01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aftering wait for a long time the page opened.